# Convertir respuesta array to LocaleString

Tags: javascript, web

Tengo una api que me devuelve como respuesta un objeto de numeros y lo quiero mostrar como moneda, esta es mi respuesta :

```
    data.result
        .sort((a, b) => b.MontoVenta - a.MontoVenta)
        .map(seller => seller.MontoVenta)
```

Eso lo muestro en una tabla pero me muestra números sin formato. Intenté formatearlo con toLocaleString pero no me funciona, por alguna razón no me renderiza los números cuando hago eso. Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: podrias agregar lo que as intentando hasta ahora? un ejemplo de la data que develve la api y el resultado esperado....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar `Intl.NumberFormat()`, como primer argumento espera el ***locale*** (la region geográfica) y como segundo argumento podes mandar un JSON para especificar cosas como:

- style: el tipo de formato que queres utilizar (decimal, currency)
- currency: la moneda

```js
let data = {"result": [{"monto":2},{"monto":3},{"monto":12},{"monto":21}]}
let dollarUS = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD",
});
let pesosAR = Intl.NumberFormat("es-AR", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "ARS",
});
let euro = Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "EUR",
});

let resultPesos = data.result.map(s => pesosAR.format(s.monto))
let resultDollar = data.result.map(s => dollarUS.format(s.monto))
let resultEuro = data.result.map(s => euro.format(s.monto))

console.log('AR', resultPesos)
console.log('USD', resultDollar)
console.log('Euro', resultEuro)
```

Comment: Gracias! Pero no me funciona. Lo que pasa es que tengo el siguiente objeto: 

{
    "00000124": {
        "2021": {
            "10": 17,
            "11": 12,
            "12": 8,
            "01": 20,
            "02": 14,
            "03": 20,
            "04": 14,
            "05": 16,
            "06": 11,
            "07": 18,
            "08": 15,
            "09": 9
        }
Pero no me deja hacerle un .map  Como tendría que hacerlo para aplicarle a cada numero el formato?

Comment: No se bien como es que lo estas intentando, pero con ese objeto que pasas vas a tener que iterarlo distinto dependiendo de que es lo que quieras mapear porque es un objeto con otra estructura

Comment: Por lo que veo ahí lo que vas a tener que solucionar es la forma de especificar los indices del objeto, ese incremento de año a año y de mes a mes. Una vez que puedas iterar el objeto, aplicar el monto podes hacerlo como lo hice con el map. Te invito a investigar e intentar hacer eso y en caso de no poder, a crear una nueva publicación para este caso así puedes mostrar como lo estas intentando. Saludos! 